# Aggregate on latest nested value

Tags: elasticsearch, aggregate, elasticsearch-aggregation, elasticsearch-query

I am trying to aggregate on the newest/latest value of a nested object.

In my case i would like to aggregate all orders by latest status event.
My document is structured like this (simplified)

```
[
  {
    "order_number": 12312,
    "events": [
      {
        "status": "picked",
        "timestamp": "2021-02-21 00:20:30"
      },
      {
        "status": "packed",
        "timestamp": "2021-02-21 00:21:43"
      },
      {
        "status": "sent",
        "timestamp": "2021-02-21 00:25:54"
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "order_number": 12313,
    "events": [
      {
        "status": "picked",
        "timestamp": "2021-02-22 12:22:34"
      },
      {
        "status": "packed",
        "timestamp": "2021-02-22 12:42:43"
      }
    ]
  }
]
```

The result of aggregation would be something like this.

```
[
  {
    "status": "sent",
    "count": 1
  },
  {
    "status": "packed",
    "count": 1
  }
]
```

After searching around i figured out that i might use the **top_hits**, but i can't get it to work properly.

Answer (score 0):

You can retrieve the document having the latest timestamp by using [top hits aggregation](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-aggregations-metrics-top-hits-aggregation.html).

Adding a working example

**Index Mapping:**

```
{
  "mappings": {
    "properties": {
      "events": {
        "type": "nested",
        "properties": {
          "timestamp": {
            "type": "date",
            "format": "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss"
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

**Index Data:**

```
{
  "order_number": 12312,
  "events": [
    {
      "status": "picked",
      "timestamp": "2021-02-21 00:20:30"
    },
    {
      "status": "packed",
      "timestamp": "2021-02-21 00:21:43"
    },
    {
      "status": "sent",
      "timestamp": "2021-02-21 00:25:54"
    }
  ]
}
  {
    "order_number": 12313,
    "events": [
      {
        "status": "picked",
        "timestamp": "2021-02-22 12:22:34"
      },
      {
        "status": "packed",
        "timestamp": "2021-02-22 12:42:43"
      }
    ]
  }
```

**Search Query:**

```
{
  "size": 0,
  "aggs": {
    "district": {
      "terms": {
        "field": "order_number"
      },
      "aggs": {
        "trucks": {
          "nested": {
            "path": "events"
          },
          "aggs": {
            "latest": {
              "top_hits": {
                "sort": [
                  {
                    "events.timestamp": {
                      "order": "desc"
                    }
                  }
                ],
                "size": 1
              }
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

**Search Result:**

```
"aggregations": {
    "district": {
      "doc_count_error_upper_bound": 0,
      "sum_other_doc_count": 0,
      "buckets": [
        {
          "key": 12312,
          "doc_count": 1,
          "trucks": {
            "doc_count": 3,
            "latest": {
              "hits": {
                "total": {
                  "value": 3,
                  "relation": "eq"
                },
                "max_score": null,
                "hits": [
                  {
                    "_index": "66322033",
                    "_type": "_doc",
                    "_id": "1",
                    "_nested": {
                      "field": "events",
                      "offset": 2
                    },
                    "_score": null,
                    "_source": {
                      "status": "sent",                   // note this
                      "timestamp": "2021-02-21 00:25:54"
                    },
                    "sort": [
                      1613867154000
                    ]
                  }
                ]
              }
            }
          }
        },
        {
          "key": 12313,
          "doc_count": 1,
          "trucks": {
            "doc_count": 2,
            "latest": {
              "hits": {
                "total": {
                  "value": 2,
                  "relation": "eq"
                },
                "max_score": null,
                "hits": [
                  {
                    "_index": "66322033",
                    "_type": "_doc",
                    "_id": "2",
                    "_nested": {
                      "field": "events",
                      "offset": 1
                    },
                    "_score": null,
                    "_source": {
                      "status": "packed",                    // note this
                      "timestamp": "2021-02-22 12:42:43"
                    },
                    "sort": [
                      1613997763000
                    ]
                  }
                ]
              }
            }
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  }
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for your answer. 

I don't want the orders with the latest status, but an overview of which status the orders are in. See my example

Comment: @ThomasBolander sorry I didn't get you. Can you please explain your use case briefly? As far as I can understand, to get an overview of which `status` the orders are in, you need to find the latest `timestamp` from the `events`, and the `status`, corresponding to that `timestamp`.

Comment: I would like an overview of how many orders there is in the different states. 

packed : 2
picked: 0
sent: 20